# Php generating speed graph

Tags: php, charts, linegraph

I have a number of data from mysql database to be populated into a graph format. The graph is speed vs time. The time will be in every minute. So far I have tried two tools one phPlot and PhpGraphLib. The first one will only plot say at most 10 points and second one give me an error of too many points. Any help on how to draw a line graph with many x-axis points? Thank you.

Comment: Why you don't try Google Charts API ? Is very easy and very nice too ! ;)

http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/chart/

Comment: google charts is good but if you have a large dataset you won't be able to call it via GET, you will need to use js and post

Comment: Mine is quite large data set on the x-axis it might every minute in between of say 10 hours. So what best method to solve on this? I do not mind on the x-axis just show the start and end time but the plot can be compress is ok with me?

Comment: @newbie14 you can still use googlecharts, just not the GET method.

Comment: here is another option you could try out too, this uses flash for charting http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/

Comment: maani also have the problem where the data gets limited cause I have a lot of x-axis data.

Comment: dear bumber how to use Googlecharts in my scenario i do not mind just to show start and end data time that will do and the rest can be compressed? Any example for me to follow please?

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple google chart wrapper in php, that i have used before

http://code.google.com/p/gchartphp/

there is a examples file with it that shows you the basics

Comment: Thank you bumber so this a basic chart rite for me to start using google chart is it? Any specific example for my case? Later if I would like to produce a pdf document by having this chart as part of the document is it possible?

Comment: google chart renders the charts as a graphic, so you could download and insert that graphic into a pdf file no problem. i have inserted graphics into pdf files using php fpdf library